# How can set width of sub div full width of sroll div?

Tags: html, css

This is my code:
I want set width of groupItemSearch full parent div:

```html
<html >
<head>    
<style>
.searchframe {
    border: 1px solid #545454;
    min-height: 80vh;    
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 290px;   
   
}
.btnMenu {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #2185D0;   
    white-space: nowrap;
   
} 
.groupItemSearch{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    width:100%;
}
.groupLeft {   
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="searchframe">
   <div class="groupItemSearch">
    <a style="Color:#ffffff;"  class="btnMenu" >External Static pressure - inchAqua</a>
    <div class="groupLeft">
    <input type="text" style="display: inline;">
    <label style="display: inline;">～</label>
    <input style="display: inline;">
    <label style="display: inline;"> inchAqua</label>
    <button style="display: inline;">Search </button>
    </div>
   </div>
      <div class="groupItemSearch">
    <a style="Color:#ffffff;"  class="btnMenu" >External Static pressure - inchAqua</a>
    <div class="groupLeft">
    <input type="text" style="display: inline;">
    <label style="display: inline;">～</label>
    <input style="display: inline;">
    <label style="display: inline;"> inchAqua</label>
    <button style="display: inline;">Search </button>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can set width of sub div full width of sroll div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have fixed the issue for you, let me know. The controls(textbox, button) was making the `width` goes beyond the `290px` and as per your requirement you need it within same width.

```css
.searchframe {
  height: 80vh;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 290px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.btnMenu {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #2185D0;
}

.groupItemSearch {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="searchframe">
    <div class="groupItemSearch">
      <a class="btnMenu">External Static pressure - inchAqua</a>
      <div class="groupLeft">
        <input type="text">
        <label>～</label>
        <input>
        <label> inchAqua</label>
        <button>Search </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you need multiple children underneath then this is how to use:

```css
.searchframe {
  height: 80vh;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 290px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btnMenu {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #2185D0;
}

.groupItemSearch {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="searchframe">
    <div class="groupItemSearch"> <a class="btnMenu">External Static pressure - inchAqua</a>
      <div class="groupLeft">
        <input type="text">
        <label>～</label>
        <input>
        <label> inchAqua</label>
        <button>Search </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="groupItemSearch"> <a class="btnMenu">External Static pressure - inchAqua</a>

      <div class="groupLeft">
        <input type="text">
        <label>～</label>
        <input>
        <label> inchAqua</label>
        <button>Search </button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="groupItemSearch"> <a class="btnMenu">External Static pressure - inchAqua</a>

      <div class="groupLeft">
        <input type="text">
        <label>～</label>
        <input>
        <label> inchAqua</label>
        <button>Search </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i had try add position:absolute to parent div , it not ok.

Comment: I didn't get it, if you see the snippet added above has `100%` width with scroll, what a I missing here?

Comment: you remove overflow-x: auto; , result is not change.

Comment: so what is it you need? you have given parent `width:260px` and you need the child to fill `100%`, my question is what is it you expecting as an output?

Comment: i want width of groupItemSearch can full searchframe when display sroll.

Comment: @DT that is exactly the child is behaving, I have updated another snippet to show the width variations with color code as yellow and red, check and let me know, child is 100% width of the parent. you can view that by increasing or decreasing the width.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210558/discussion-between-d-t-and-manjuboyz).